# Is it correct to use "Dear friends" in formal or informal letters?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is it correct to use "Dear friends" in formal or informal letters?

Can I use it?

And if not, what *can* I use ?

Comment: Yes, the word *dear* is very  formal if it is used in formal occasions and informal when it is in informal occasions.  But do you be so formal with your friends? In formal occasions we usually do not address others as 'friends'.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to use 'Dear friends' informally, but never formally.

The very definition of formal is: done in accordance with convention or etiquette; suitable for or constituting an official or important occasion.

As such a formal letter would conform to Dear Sir, Dear Madam, Dear Mr. Jones etc.  Not Dear friends.

For a more formal salutation to multiple recipients, I would use 'Dear All'.

Comment: But you have not provided the OP with a plural alternative.

Comment: Well spotted, Nigel.  I have edited the original answer to include a plural alternative.

Comment: And I have upvoted it for you.

Comment: I'd say 'Dear All' sounds quite informal. But answers on ELU need to be backed by supporting references. Otherwise, they sound like (and may be) mere personal opinions.